# PHP Show Div Amongst Other Divs

Tags: php

I'm creating an articles wesbite and want to show a grid of 8 articles with an advert placed somwhere within that grid using PHP.  So it should look like (For Example):

```
[ Article ][ Article ][ Article ]
[ Article ][ Article ][ ADVERTS ]
[ Article ][ Article ][ Article ]
```

So the PHP code I have is:

```
$get_article_sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 8";
$get_article_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_article_sql);
while($article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_article_res)){
    $article_id = $article["id"];
    etc...

    $list_articles .= "


    <div class=\"selectArticle selectArticleClear\">
        <a href=\"article.php?id=$article_id&title=$article_url_title\">
            <div class=\"selectArticleImage\">
                <img class=\"selectArticleImage\" src=\"images/$article_year/$article_id$article_photo\" alt=\"$article_alt\" />
                <div class=\"selectArticleCover\"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class=\"selectArticleTitle\"><a href=\"article.php?id=$article_id&title=$article_url_title\">$article_title</a></div>
        <div class=\"selectArticleText\">$article_article...<br>| ... <a href=\"article.php?id=$article_id&title=$article_url_title\">Read On</a> &raquo&raquo;</div>
    </div>

    ";
}
```

I then have my Advert:

```
$advert = "<div class="advert">ADVERT CODE</div>";
```

How do I place the `$advert` inside the `$list_articles` string at position 6 for example?

Comment: Create a counter, increase it every loop and add a simple if statement? Example: `if ($counter == 6) $list_articles .= $advert;`

Comment: Make a table using HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Count 6 outputs and concatenate your advert div:

```
...
$i = 1;
while($article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_article_res)){

  if(6 === $i++) {
    $list_articles .= '<div class="advert">ADVERT CODE</div>';
  }
...
```

Comment: Thank you, but where exaclty should this be placed?

Comment: In place of the single `while` line.

Answer (score 0):

On your

```
 <div class=\"selectArticleTitle\"><a href=\"article.php?id=$article_id&title=$article_url_title\">$article_title</a></div>
```

put another div followed by it for better div organization then use css to position it

do your positioning for

```
[ Article ][ Article ][ Article ]
[ Article ][ Article ][ ADVERTS ]
[ Article ][ Article ][ Article ]
```

with CSS

Comment: How do I position that with CSS?

Comment: here is a perfect example, look at the fiddle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734748/div-in-div-in-rows-and-columns

Comment: Honestly just make a table with CSS/HTML. The rest will easily fall into place.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a counter like this :

```
 $i=0;
 $advert = "<div class="advert">ADVERT CODE</div>";   
    while($article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_article_res)){
        $article_id = $article["id"];

        if($i==5){
           $list_articles .=$advert;
        }
        $list_articles .= "

        <div class=\"selectArticle selectArticleClear\">
           <a href=\"article.php?id=$article_id&title=$article_url_title\">
                <div class=\"selectArticleImage\">
                    <img class=\"selectArticleImage\" src=\"images/$article_year/$article_id$article_photo\" alt=\"$article_alt\" />
                    <div class=\"selectArticleCover\"></div>
               </div>
            </a>
            <div class=\"selectArticleTitle\"><a href=\"article.php?id=$article_id&title=$article_url_title\">$article_title</a></div>
            <div class=\"selectArticleText\">$article_article...<br>| ... <a href=\"article.php?id=$article_id&title=$article_url_title\">Read On</a> &raquo&raquo;</div>
        </div>

        ";


       $i++;
    }
```

Comment: This code **drops and never outputs** the fifth element came from a query.

Comment: @mudasobwa I didn't bother to output it since OP never asked for it.

Comment: You're right @mudasobwa! Just tried it on a paginated page - Any way this can be modified to do the job?

Comment: What’s wrong with using my answer and putting the code I provided in place of `while($article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_article_res)){` in original code?